# Second nested query returns all NULLS even though returns values when run alone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to recreate an Access database report using nested queries in SQL. I've gotten over the hurdle of actually converting the scripting but have been unable to get the results I expect. The below script returns what I expect for sub1 but sub2 returns all nulls. Can anyone offer any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

As always, thank you for any help!

```
SELECT  SUB1.CUSNAME, SUB1.CO_INSTALL AS Install, SUB1.SALESREPID AS [Sales Rep], SUB1.CUSORDID AS [Job #], SUB1.LINE_PARTID, SUB2.POID AS PO, 
        SUB2.ORDER_DATE AS Ord, SUB2.PROMISE_DATE AS Req, SUB2.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE AS Rcd, SUB2.SHIPTO_NAME AS [Where Sent], SUB2.VendorName AS Vendor
FROM            
(SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID AS CUSORDID, CUSTOMER_ORDER.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE AS CO_INSTALL, CUSTOMER.NAME AS CUSNAME, CUSTOMER_ORDER.SALESREP_ID AS SALESREPID, 
               CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_TYPE AS CUSORDTYPE, CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS, CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID AS LINE_PARTID, CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY, CUST_ORDER_LINE.LINE_STATUS, 
               CUST_ORDER_LINE.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE AS LINE_INSTALL, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.RECEIVED_QTY, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.SUPPLY_BASE_ID AS SUB1BASE, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.SUPPLY_LOT_ID, 
               DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.SUPPLY_SPLIT_ID, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.SUPPLY_SEQ_NO, CUSTOMER_ORDER.USER_4, CUSTOMER_ORDER.USER_5
               FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER INNER JOIN
                    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID INNER JOIN
                        DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                            CUST_ORDER_LINE ON DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.DEMAND_SEQ_NO = CUST_ORDER_LINE.LINE_NO AND DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.DEMAND_BASE_ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID 
                            ON CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID
                WHERE  (CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS <> 'C') AND (CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS <> 'X') AND (DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK.SUPPLY_BASE_ID IS NOT NULL)) 
                AS SUB1 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID AS WO_BASE, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_NO, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_SEQ_NO, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_TYPE, 
               WORK_ORDER.STATUS AS WO_STAT, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.SUPPLY_TYPE, DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.SUPPLY_BASE_ID AS SUB2BASE, PURCHASE_ORDER.ID AS POID, PURCHASE_ORDER.VENDOR_ID, 
               VENDOR.NAME AS VendorName, PURCHASE_ORDER.ORDER_DATE, PURCHASE_ORDER.DESIRED_RECV_DATE AS DESRECDATE, PURCHASE_ORDER.PROMISE_DATE, 
               PURCHASE_ORDER.LAST_RECEIVED_DATE, SHIPTO_ADDRESS.NAME AS SHIPTO_NAME, PURCHASE_ORDER.STATUS AS PO_STAT, PURCHASE_ORDER.BUYER
               FROM WORK_ORDER INNER JOIN
                        DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK AS DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1 ON WORK_ORDER.SUB_ID = DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_SUB_ID AND 
                        WORK_ORDER.SPLIT_ID = DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_SPLIT_ID AND WORK_ORDER.LOT_ID = DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_LOT_ID AND 
                        WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID = DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.DEMAND_BASE_ID INNER JOIN
                        PURCHASE_ORDER LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            SHIPTO_ADDRESS ON PURCHASE_ORDER.SHIPTO_ADDR_NO = SHIPTO_ADDRESS.ADDR_NO ON DEMAND_SUPPLY_LINK_1.SUPPLY_BASE_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID INNER JOIN
                                VENDOR ON PURCHASE_ORDER.VENDOR_ID = VENDOR.ID
) 
AS SUB2 
ON SUB1.SUB1BASE = SUB2.SUB2BASE
WHERE (SUB1.CO_INSTALL IS NOT NULL) AND (UPPER(SUB1.CUSORDID) LIKE 'E%' OR UPPER(SUB1.CUSORDID) like 'D%') 
ORDER BY Install
```

Comment: This is a lot to view. Reducing to minimally reproduce output is desired. Not that this is the problem, but I would consider changing your output column titled `where` to something else. Also, when looking for strings using `like`, you may want to cast to upper case such as `upper(sub1.cusordid) like 'E%'`. Do any of the sub queries produce the output you expect? Also, in sub1, why are you using `having` instead of placing that criteria in a `where` clause?

Comment: I cannot say why your sub1 has no data. The only thing I see is that column names in the join criteria usually match (like in `SUB_ID = DEMAND_SUB_ID`), with the exception of `SUPPLY_BASE_ID = PURCHASE_ORDER.ID`. Are you comparing the correct IDs here?

Comment: On a side note: You are not really aggregating (i.e. no sums, no counts, etc.), but merely removing duplicates. This is easier to read with `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT columns GROUP BY same columns`. (And why do you expect duplicates anyway? Can't you somehow prevent from getting them instead of having to remove them?)

Comment: All the other suggestions not withstanding, sub1 IS returning data. It's sub2 that comes up all nulls. I even tried changing the select for sub2 to a select * and it STILL returns ALL nulls. If I run it as a standalone select it return plenty of values.

Comment: I implemented some (all?) of the suggestions into my original post (thanks everyone!). Hopefully this is a bit more palatable. I still have the same issue though - EVERYTHING coming from the SUB2 query is returning NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
select ...
from sub1 full outer join sub2 on sub1.sub1base = sub2.sub2base
where sub1.co_install is not null and ...
```

The full outer join tells the DBMS you don't only want subxbase matches, but also all sub1 that have no sub2 match and all sub2 that have no sub1 match.

If a sub2 row has no match in sub1, it will be in the result with all sub1 columns set to null. But as you only want rows where sub1.co_install is not null, you dismiss these outer joined rows. Your query becomes in fact:

```
select ...
from sub1 left outer join sub2 on sub1.sub1base = sub2.sub2base
where sub1.co_install is not null and ...
```

For all sub1 that have no match in sub2, you get a row with all sub2 columns set to null.

You say that everything you get from sub2 is null. That seems to indicate that there are no subxbase matches, but only mismatches. As you dismiss all sub2 that have no match in sub1, you only see all sub1 that have no match in sub2. And hence you don't see any value in sub2 columns.

Comment: correct! It turns out all of attempts were using the wrong pairing from the 2 subquery tables. After pairing the correct field from the 2 sides everything started working!